# Center div have height limit

Tags: html, css

I have three columns, but in the center one I can display only limited number of paragraphs.
If I add, for example, 15 paragraphs, only first 11 paragraphs will be displayed. It's like the div have set height parameter. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
<div id="left" style="float:left; width:250px;"></div>
<div id="right" style="float:right; width:250px;"></div>
<div id="center" style="margin:0;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left;` also to your `#center` element

or if you don't want it floated than: `overflow:auto;`

Comment: Be careful if you add float:left as you will then also need a set width (assuming a fixed width layout otherwise this method is of no use) because the float will stretch with content and won't fit inside the gap. The overflow method is fine as long as you don't need visible overflow.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` instead:

CSS

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.side {
    width: 250px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="cell side">Left</div>
    <div class="cell">Center</div>
    <div class="cell side">Right</div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming these are the building blocks for your layout, with a centered area and sidebars on the left and right. Using `table` has the benefit that all cells maintain the same height; `float` can be fickle.